# Has this conjecture been discovered before? (Concerns prime numbers and not $\#(n)$ like in a question similar to this)

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, conjectures

This is my second question today (I want to keep my major questions seperate):

> Let's denote the $n^{th}$ prime number as $p_n$. Given the equation:
>
> $$\frac{p_1p_2p_3 \cdots p_n}{1 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + \cdots + p_n} = \{x_m : x_m \in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$$
>
> Now the $LHS$ is not always equal to a positive integer, but when it is, it is equal to $x_m$. The first positive integer it will be equal to (which is $1$) is denoted as $x_1$ such that $m = 1$ and $n = 2$, and the second integer (which is $715$) is denoted as $x_2$ such that $m = 2$ and $n = 6$ etc.
>
> **Conjecture:**
>
> $$δ(x_m) = \{2^{2m - 1} : m > 1 \ \land \ δ(x_m) = \text{number of divisors of $x_m$ including $x_m$ itself}\}$$
>
> $$m > 1 \because δ(x_1) = δ(1) = 1 \neq 2^{2\times 1 - 1} = 2$$

Is there a way to prove/disprove this? This is my own conjecture and I put my own little symbols to it. Could somebody please explain to me why this works and any examples where it doesn't (if they exist)? If this is somebody else's conjecture then I will delete this post. I am in Year $9$, so my skill level in mathematics is not too high (compared to most users on this site), so I am sure somebody else must have discovered this.

Thanks to this site, the only *non-Year $9$* maths I am familiar with include:

- Sets
- Matrices
- Sum/product series Σ and Π
- Imaginary (lateral) numbers $\sqrt{\text{negative}}$ (not particularly complex numbers $a + bi$)
- Quadratic equations
- Logarithms $\log_bn = m$
- Trigonometry $\Delta ABC$ and
- Linear Graphs $y = mx + c$.

I guess these are the only things that may make you wonder if I actually am in Year $9$. Everything else that what a Year $9$ is usually taught, I also know. If you are using other techniques and ways of proving/disproving my conjecture, please be clear and try not to skip too many steps. I have not decided to name my conjecture as of yet (and I don't want to be selfish by naming it based on my *own* name) but I want to see what you think of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question needs some serious work. The prime number is denoted $p_n$ but $n$ is the $n$'th prime number? And in the next part, $m$ is the $n$'th integer?

Comment: Note that if an integer $n\gt 1$ is square-free (or equivalently has $r$ distinct prime factors with no squares of primes as factors) the number of divisors of $n$ (including the two "improper" divisors $1$ and $n$, which it is convenient to include) will be a power of $2$, namely $2^r$. This is a sufficient, but not a necessary, condition for a power of $2$ to arise. For example $24$ has eight factors. You might want to see if you can work out how the number of divisors relates to the prime factorisation.

Comment: First of all, $$\frac{p_1p_2}{1 + p_1 + p_2} = x_1=1,$$ not $6$. Your claim is true for $m=2,3,4,5$ but increasingly wrong for all higher $m$ I investigated (up to $m=33$). The number of divisors is always a power of $2$, naturally (because $x_m$ is a product of different primes), but the exponent is higher.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yes that was a very silly mistake of mine. I do not know WHAT I was thinking.

Comment: If we assume the random model for the primes then there should be only finitely many such $n$.